# View expiry date of an epub file

Tags: windows, epub

Is there an easy way to see the expiry date of an epub file? Maybe an explorer extension that shows it in the files details pane? Or a script?

The software that I use to synchronize with my Sony e-reader (Reader for PC) does not show the date, but just gives a vague error ('the file cannot be opened') if I try to open the file. The application is also kind of slow to open a book, so this way is not ideal.

Adobe Digital Editions does show wether the book is expired, but since it doesn't synchronize with my e-reader, I have to manually import the book first to see if it's expired.